# Yii: belongs to through

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, yii

I have 3 models:

```
Groups
     id
     name

Users
     id
     group_id
     login
     // ....

Messages
     id
     user_id
     title
     body
     // ....
```

Users belong to Groups and have many Messages

```
 'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Groups', 'group_id'),
 'messages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Messages', 'user_id')
```

Groups have many Users

```
 'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Users', 'group_id')
```

Messages belong to Users

```
 'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id')
```

Belongs to relation in Yii has no `$through` so how do I define relation connecting Messages and Groups (i.e. Messages belong to Groups)?

**UPD:** A dirty hack. Define new type of relation:

```
class BelongsToThrough extends CBelongsToRelation {
    public $through;
}
```

set it as relation type in `Messages`:

```
'group' => array('BelongsToThrough', 'Groups', 'group_id', 'through' => 'user')
```

and it works. Somehow. Could someone please explain how is that working?

Comment: look at the source of [CHasOneRelation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L2155)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build a bridge table(groups_messages) between messages and groups and connect them like this:

```
'groups' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Groups', 'groups_messages(message_id, group_id)')
```

Comment: What for? I need just another join in query. Adding another table just to relate them is not smart and because Yii can't handle related records operations itself (remove/update) I'll have to add some behavior. So table + behavior dependency. Overkill.